# Jquery .not() based on child elements

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

http://jsfiddle.net/L7axv/

I have a column in a table dedicated to comments. I need for when the cell is clicked, a popup appears allowing users to add comments. Inside the cell will be existing comments and a way to remove them. When you click to remove a comment, you should not then see the popup.

I tried:

```
$("td").not('div').click(function(){
    $('#popup').show();
});   //was hoping this would mean if td is clicked, and clicked area is not a div


$("div").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[e.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)** on `div` to prevent `.click()` event bubble up the DOM tree:

```
$("div").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7axv/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
$("td").click(function(e){
    if( !$(e.target).is('div') ) {
        $('#popup').show();
    } else {
        $(e.target).hide();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L7axv/4/

If the clicked element is not a div, show the popup. You can actually delete the div click handler using this

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event to click on a column by using hierarchical selectors
provided by jQuery.

```
$('#table td:eq(index)').click(function(){
 $('#popup').show();
});
```

PS: index is a number depending on which  you want click to be associated.